# C# 9 - updating init-only properties on records with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-9.0

C# 9 introduced [records](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#records) and [init-only properties](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/#init-only-properties) to make it easier to write immutable reference objects.

I've been trying to convert an old Entity Framework project to use these features, but I've hit a bit of friction between immutable C# records with init-only properties and trying to make changes to the underlying SQL records.

Maybe I'm just pushing against the flow, but is there a pattern for defining your C# classes as immutable init-only records but still allowing for updates to the underlying SQL data?

My current (working) code which uses mutable *classes*:

**MyReport.cs**

```cs
namespace MyNamespace 
{
    public sealed class MyReport
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ReportId { get; set; }

        public DateTime ReportDate { get; set; }
        public bool ReadyToUse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MyApp.cs**

```cs
using (var dbContext = DbContext.Create(connectionString))
{
    // create a new report
    var myReport = new MyReport
    {
        ReportDate = reportDate,
        ReadyToUse = false
    };

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    ... do some other stuff ...

    // update the report status
    usageReport.ReadyToUse = true;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, if I change the implementation of MyReport to use C# 9 records and init-only properties:

**MyReport.cs**

```cs
namespace MyNamespace 
{
    public sealed record MyReport
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ReportId { get; init; }

        public DateTime ReportDate { get; init; }
        public bool ReadyToUse { get; init; }
    }
}
```

then I start getting an error:

> CS8852 - Init-only property or indexer can only be assigned in an object initializer

on the line

```
usageReport.ReadyToUse = true;
```

I've got no complaints about the error because you obviously can't update an init-only property outside of the constructor, but I was wondering if there's a good way to work with init-only properties and mutable SQL data in Entity Framework.

I thought about doing this:

```cs
using (var dbContext = DbContext.Create(connectionString))
{
    // create a new report
    var myReport = new MyReport
    {
        ReportDate = reportDate,
        ReadyToUse = false
    };

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    ... do some other stuff ...

    // update the report status
    usageReport = usageReport with { ReadyToUse = true };
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

but then I'm not sure how to tell the `dbContext` to treat the new usageReport as a change to the underlying SQL data without triggering a massive delete and re-insert.

Comment: I am not sure how records actually relate to the deadlock problem on bulk inserts. If you replace the record with a poco, does it still cause the issue ?

Comment: @00110001 - The issue is that the deadlock means I need to do a 3-stage insert as shown, and update the ```ReadyToUse``` property when it's complete, *but* it's not clear to me how to update a SQL record using Entity Framework if I switch my legacy code with ```class```es to use init-only ```record```s instead. My waffling on about deadlocks was really to justify why I need to modify the Report record after creation :-).

Comment: @00110001 - I'll try to edit the question distill out my actual problem with editing SQL records backing a ```record``` with init-only properties...

Comment: @00110001 - I've removed all the stuff about deadlocks - it was all a bit of a distraction from the real question...

Comment: There's not enough info to come up with a "right" answer for this question, but it sounds like maybe your data model doesn't quite represent your business model. For example, maybe a Report has two parts: The ID and creation date, which shouldn't change, and a Status which should. Maybe the immutable part can be a record in one table, and the ReportStatus can be a class in another table? The tricky thing is you won't be able to have a navigation property from `Report` to `ReportStatus`, so maybe it really makes more sense to use a class with some init-only properties?

Comment: Can you explain why you wanted to use records in the first place?

Comment: Are you sure the `with` expression causes a massive delete and re-insert? `with` should give you a shallow copy and the entity should be tracked; no?

Comment: You wrote: _C# 9 introduced records and init-only properties to make it easier to write **immutable** reference objects._, then you wrote _if there's a good way to work with init-only properties and **mutable** SQL data in Entity Framework_ - Can you see a conflict of those statements?

Comment: @Fabio - yeah, I understand the conflict, which is why I'm basically looking for a sensible way to resolve it :-). I guess I want to treat the in-memory records as immutable "snapshots" of the underlying business object, but at the same time be able to update the underlying object in storage with new "snapshots". I think the issue is Entity Framework isn't designed to work that way - it seems to expect your entities to be mutable poco references (*mutable* records work fine too, btw) which it tracks changes to and then applies to the underlying storage.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - i'll try it and see today, but my understanding is that ```with``` will create a *new* record with the new values, but Entity Framework is tracking a reference to the *old* record so won't think it needs to do anything when you call ```SaveChanges```.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I'm using records because I've found it much easier to reason about behaviour of immutable objects in other projects, and records seem to be the idiomatic way to do this in C# 9. I've not had to wrangle with Entity Framework in those other projects though so maybe they just don't play nicely together like I'm trying to make them...

Comment: @mclayton this is bad EF Core code records or no records. `SaveChanges` is meant to be called only at the end, persisting all changes to the database. by calling it repeatedly you break DbContext's Unit-of-Work and disconnected semantics. I suspect you get deadlocks because you added an explicit transaction to get back UoW. If you want some properties to be updatable, don't make them `init-only`. The bad EF code is far more damaging though

Comment: Nothing prevents you from making `ReadyToUse` mutable and write `public bool ReadyToUse { get; set; }`. On the other hand, why save an incomplete `Report` object *at all*? You don't need a `ReadyToUse` flag if you don't save incomplete objects. What is your code trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Thanks for pointing that out. The things I've read about records had led me to believe they were inherently immutable, but it turns out they're merely immutable _by default_. So this is really less a question about using records and more about using immutable models.

Comment: @mclayton: If your objective is to keep your objects immutable, then you should design an immutable data model. For example, rather than a field that says whether the report is ready, you could have a separate table that gets an entry when the report becomes ready (or which gets a new timestamped entry whenever the report's current state changes). But Entity Framework was designed with a mutable, relational object model in mind, so I'd personally recommend using mutable types in your EF context and map them to immutable DTOs where it makes sense.

Comment: You should not use record types with Entity Framework, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/records

Comment: @cremor - could you expand your comment? I read the article but it doesn’t mention best practices for EF, so I’d be interested in hearing specifically why you should not use records with EF…

Comment: @mclayton See https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/4438

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You certainly **can** use the C# 9 records with Entity Framework. What you can **not** do is to use them with the default behavior of "retreive an entity, update its properties and call `.SaveChanges()`.

Instead you must use the copy-and-update syntax of records in conjunction with the DbContext.Update() function:

```
var report = dbContext.Set<MyReport>().AsNoTracking().First(...some linq query...);
var updatedReport = report with {ReadyToUse = true};
dbContext.Update(updatedRecord);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

**IMPORTANT:** You need to call `.AsNoTracking ()` on every query or disable the change tracker to prevent EF from tracking the retrieved entity. If you don't, it will throw an exception in `` .SaveChanges () '' saying that another entity with the same key is already being tracked. If you decide to declare all your entities as records, disabling the tracking system is the best option and will have a positive impact on the overall performance of the application.

**EXTRA:** The solution is exactly the same when working with F# records.